# ORA-01861 error on NUMBER(8) column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have the following SQL, which basically checks whether the "SYSDATE" fits in between specific dates(i.e. some date <= SYSDATE <= some date + 30 days).

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(T1.WEB_STR_DT, 'YYYYMMDD')) AND
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(T1.WEB_STR_DT, 'YYYYMMDD')) + 30
```

The problem I am facing is that I get ORA-01861 even the date is in the valid date format(yyyymmdd).

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: `TO_CHAT`?  Twice?  Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be converting `sysdate` to and from a string at all, as that is wasteful but is also doing implicit conversion - which is what is causing the ORA-018611 error. Your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is not `YYYYMMDD`; you explicitly convert the date to that format, then try to convert the resulting string back to a date using whatever your NLS settings currently are:

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')) from dual;

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD') from dual;

TO_DATE(T
---------
13-APR-17
```

But instead of that you can just use `trunc(sysdate)`. That strips the time back to midnight, so it would match if `WEB_STR_DT` represented today.

That isn't the only problem though. You shouldn't be storing dates as numbers in the first place, but if you must convert a number like `20170413` to a date then you need to convert it to a string first and then convert that string to a date.

Essentially you have your parentheses in the wrong place, and instead of

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(T1.WEB_STR_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

you should have:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(T1.WEB_STR_DT), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Your code is doing the equivalent of:

```
select to_date(to_char(20170413, 'YYYYMMDD')) from dual;

ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

because you're attempting to use date format model elements to convert a number to a string. With that parenthesis moved you do end up with the equivalent date.

So, you can do:

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(T1.WEB_STR_DT), 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(T1.WEB_STR_DT), 'YYYYMMDD') + 30
```

Even the explicit `TO_CHAR()` calls are a bit unnecessary, since you aren't supply a format model for those, so even simpler would be:

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(T1.WEB_STR_DT, 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND TO_DATE(T1.WEB_STR_DT, 'YYYYMMDD') + 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Number conversion issues (and what is `to_chat`?)... I assume you just want date with no time.

Try TRUNC:

```
WHERE trunc(sysdate) between trunc(T1.WEB_STR_DT) and trunc(T1.WEB_STR_DT)+30
```